# Complexity of graph 3 coloring and counting algorithm

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-colorings

3-coloring a graph $G$ is equivalent to partitioning the
vertices of $G$ in three independent sets.

The smallest independent set $A$ is at most $n/3$ where $n$
is the order of $G$.

We have $G \setminus A$ is bipartite graph, and the bipartitions
can be found in polynomial in $n$ time.

This gives graph coloring and counting of 3 colorings algorithm:

```
For one coloring:

  Enumerate independent sets A up to size n/3
  If G \ A is bipartite report 3 colorable and stop

For counting colorings:

   set cols:=0
   Enumerate independent sets A up to size n/3
   If G \ A is bipartite set cols := cols + number_of_2_colorings of G \ A
   # G \ A might not be connected
```

> Q1 What is the complexity of these algorithms?

Crude upper bound:  All subsets (not necessary independent) of size at most 
$n/3$ experimentally is about $1.883^n$

> Q2 What is state of the art of counting 3 colorings?

Comment: Your second algorithm is double-counting colorings in which two sets have size $\le n/3$.

Comment: @SamZbarsky Thanks, you are right. Can we modify the algorithm to keep track of colorings where two color classes are < n/3?

Comment: Such an algorithm may be incorrect, as any 3-coloring of $C_5$ has color classes of size 1,2,2, and n=5.

Comment: @LeechLattice I don't think $C_5$ is problem. Problem appear to be $K_3 \cup K_1$ with sizes 1,1,2 and n=4

Answer (score 2):

For finding colorings, let $A=K_4 \cup \bar{K^m}$, which is a $K_4$ and $m$ disjoint vertices. The algorithm keeps enumerating independent sets without success, as $A$ is not 3-colorable.

For counting colorings, the complement of a complete graph takes the longest time.

Both have complexity of the order $1.883^n c$ where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: Thanks. As per comment in the question, the counting algorithm doubly counts when two color classes are of size < n/3. Can we modify the algorithm to count correctly?